# Netflix Windows Media Center Plugin Missing Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-media-center, netflix

Due to various reasonings I upgraded to Windows 8.1 Pro. I also purchased the Media Center addon from MS. On Windows 7 I had Netflix for Media Center, in Windows 8.1 I cannot seem to download/find Netflix in Media Center.

I want this over the app for use with the MCE remote. I'm uninterested in alternatives at this time. How can I get the Netflix plugin to show up with Windows 8.1 Pro's Media Center.

Comment: Well Media Center didn't change. Can you link to the plugin in question? Have you installed the plugin? I had no trouble finding a working link to `NetflixinWindowsMediaCenter.exe`

Comment: The problem you will face is that Media Center has not been updated in years and Silerlight support by Netflix is not the best for a varity of reasons.  You might have to **consider** alternatives.